# How to perform a select statement from inside a c-extension

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I managed to get a c-extension to compile and run with the help of the official documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/xfunc-c.html.

Now I don't see in the examples provided a way to perform a `select` inside of a c-extension. Generally I don't know where to look for documentatin of how to perform any "normal" sql-statements inside a c-extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think are looking for the sibling chapter on the [Server Programming Interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/spi.html).  Contrib contains a whole directory of example code for using SPI, called 'contrib/spi'.  There are many other modules in contrib that also use SPI as a component of their operations.